# Overcurrent/short circuit protection using an op-amp and a MOSFET

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, short-circuit, circuit-protection, over-current

I wanted a circuit to limit the current to say 4 A, and found [this](https://www.hackatronic.com/over-current-short-circuit-protection-using-lm358-op-amp/), but it doesn't work in the Proteus simulator. What's wrong with this circuit? Are there any ways to improve it?

Here is my expectation of the circuit:
When the inverting input is higher than the non-inverting one, the MOSFET turns off and now non-inverting input is higher so roughly Vcc appears on the gate of MOSFET and turns it on again, is this correct?

If this happens we have pulses of full current passing through the FET and load. Shouldn't it go and stay off until the short-circuit disappears?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct: the circuit will oscillate rather than latch.

The positive feedback was perhaps an effort to make it latch, but by inspection, we see that`-IN` will be pulled to GND through R1, while `+IN` can only be pulled down a small amount by the 100k resistor -- at most, by 0.9V (for VR1 at mid-scale), always remaining positive.

We can address this by pulling up the feedback signal with additional resistors:

[image: Current limiting latching circuit]

R5 and R6 values will have to be determined by application design.  For a 4A system, R1 should be smaller to save on voltage drop and power dissipation, and then the voltage range for VR1 (and at the op-amp inputs in general) should be lower.  VR1 range can be reduced by putting a resistor in series with it on the +9V side (the side towards U1).  Hysteresis can also be increased by putting a resistor in series with VR1 wiper.

Note that an LM358 will take a relative eternity to respond, in electrical terms -- about 20µs.  In this time, Q1 is *unlikely* to be destroyed (actually, at typical ratings, it should be okay for closer to 100µs; exact limits can be calculated from operating conditions and the datasheet SOA or transient thermal curves), so that's probably fine, but if a faster-acting fuse is desired, consider using a comparator proper, like LM393 (the circuit will be only a little different; a pull-up resistor from pin 8 to pin 1 is required).

Incidentally, turn-off is assured: LM358 is a single-supply type op-amp.  Its output can pull very low (nearly to GND) when the load is small, which is the case here (only R4 sources a small current into it).  It won't saturate very high (when the output is "on"), but still enough for Q1 to turn on.  (Using an IRL540 might be preferable, though.)

Note also that this circuit is inherently current-limiting: suppose the load is momentarily short-circuited.  Q1 has 9V on the gate, so it's solidly on; current and thus R1 voltage rises.  It self-limits when V(R1) is a bit below 9V - V<sub>GS(th)</sub> -- by how much, depends on the load current (see the MOSFET drain curves), but expect V(R1) to self-limit to around 5-6V.  (Or really, more like 3-5V considering LM358's V<sub>OH</sub>.)  The remaining load voltage is dropped across the transistor, so it will heat up quickly in this condition (e.g., maybe it's dropping 20V * 10A = 200W, that's a *lot* of power for a TO-220!).  The op-amp/comparator needs to turn it off before destruction.

Note that this circuit still isn't very good, as it draws high idle current (the 7809 regulator plus op-amp cost several mA), it has no transient protection (other than overcurrent; I would like to see an R+C and TVS at the output); it could stand a reset button, or start/stop buttons, or an auto-reset timer; thermal protection would be welcome; maybe UVLO to avoid erratic/erroneous operation during startup/shutdown or at low-supply conditions e.g. on battery power; etc.  These are all issues largely solved by using proper "eFuse", load switch, hot-swap / wired-OR controllers, etc. ICs.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this circuit?  Please post a link.

When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean?  What does it do / not do?

What is the purpose of R4?

A minor problem is that the output stage of an LM358 cannot swing all the way down to GND.  It can get close, but whether or not this is enough to turn off Q1 when VR1 is dialed all the way down depends on the FET's datasheet.

4 A through 1 ohm (R1) will generate 16 W, so you will need something larger than a 2 W part.  Also, at 4 A the voltage drop across R1 will be 4 V.  You don't say what Vcc is, but whatever load this is driving will not see the full Vcc across it.

To your question:  Given that we have almost zero information to work with, my ***guess*** is that R4 is creating positive feedback and is causing U1 (the opamp) to saturate.  Does this sound like a fit for the symptoms you are seeing?

Comment: It says on the image; little digging finds: https://www.hackatronic.com/over-current-short-circuit-protection-using-lm358-op-amp/